# Crystal case to SSRS Switch statement

Tags: ssrs-2008, crystal-reports-2008

How can I re-write the following Formula from Crystal Reports in SSRS

```
  select {spAR6100b_allcompanies;1.artyp}
    case 'BCS','CIG','HUM','INA','INS','MNG','PHC','SEC','SPC','TRI','UHC','WMD' : 'Primary'
    case 'COI','ICO','INP','MCO','COI' : 'Secondary'
 default: ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS expressions generally don't work very well for `IN` comparisons.

There are a few options.

Use a `Switch` and a set of linked `Or` statements:

```
=Switch(Fields!arTyp.Value = "BCS" or Fields!arTyp.Value = "BCS" or Fields!arTyp.Value = "HUM", "Primary"
, Fields!arTyp.Value = "COI" or Fields!arTyp.Value = "ICO", "Secondary"
, True, "")
```

I've only included a few of your cases and you can see it's already long - you would need to add as many values as you need.

With string matches you can streamline this a bit by checking if the field value is in a string of match values:

```
=Switch(InStr(",BCS,CIG,HUM,", "," & Fields!arTyp.Value & ",") > 0, "Primary"
, InStr(",COI,ICO,INP,", "," & Fields!arTyp.Value & ",") > 0, "Secondary"
, True, "")
```

We wrap everything in commas to prevent false positives on part matches. Again, add all the required values into the string list of match values.

Finally, you could use custom code for this comparison and move the comparison to a VB.NET type function embedded in the report.